# Is porting qt to another OS as simple as this?

Tags: qt

The article [Porting Qt for Embedded Linux to Another Operating System](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt-embedded-porting-operatingsystem.html) lists five things you have to do to port Qt for Embedded Linux to another OS. From the article:

> There are several issues to be aware of if you plan to do your own port to another operating system. In particular you must resolve Qt for Embedded Linux's shared memory and semaphores (used to share window regions), and you must provide something similar to Unix-domain sockets for inter-application communication. You must also provide a screen driver, and if you want to implement sound you must provide your own sound server. Finally you must modify the event dispatcher used by Qt for Embedded Linux.

Is it really this easy to port Qt to another OS, or have i missed some information?

Comment: None of those things sound particularly easy to me.

Comment: The listed steps shouldn't be too complicated given that you have an OS that supports the mechanisms described in the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this in more detail I have come to the conclusion that the article "Porting Qt for Embedded Linux to Another Operating System" assumes that you are porting Qt to a very "linux-like" OS.

Answer (score 3):

Another important component to port would be QAtomic, to ensure that you can have atomic operations and implicit sharing working well. See also

http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2007/08/28/say-hello-to-qatomicint-and-qatomicpointer/

Answer (score 2):

Since Qt has been ported a large number of times it seems logical that it would be inherently simple.  However the issue really is on the platform you are porting to and how many features it currently supports.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you find all those things easy, then the port is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted this and currently making progress.
Some difficulties:

IDE  - I have to manually add all Qt files and fight the compiler with #ifdefs until it builds with all dependencies in place.

Linux(ness) - I've had to disable all Linux/Windows things that are not supported in my target OS: threads, sockets, processes. Even the timers are slightly different.

Tips:
Start small : I compiled QtCore as a standard lib within my IDE, next up is QtGui which is a behemoth compared to QtCore.

I plan to run only a single QThread, so I have to artificially made a Thread object to avoid null pointers. You cannot compile out Thread information as it is key to all QObjects.

So far I have an qeventloop running within a qcoreapplication. 
I wrote some inline assembly but had serious difficulties with my IDE and compilation. I left it in C++ and let the assembler handle it for me. Because I am single-threaded, I am not too concerned with shared data/ exclusive access as required by the atomic operations.